# How to delete all comments from Stored Procedures in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, security

Could yo please tell me whether you know some approach to achieve this ?
I thought abouy delete all from syscomments but it seems to be more info there..

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Comment: Not sure if this forum is the best place for this question. Stackoverflow or ServerFault can be better options. Also, try to provide more info about your problem. It's souding too much generic IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

take a copy of dbschema.pl from [here](http://www.peppler.org/downloads/), export all of your stored procs, then process with a perl script, and reimport.